# Unity, C#, 2D : how to set a UI canvas item(button) position to the same position as another gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am attempting to have a button appear in the same position as a box through code so that when called this function moves the button game object to where ever the menu box gameobject is

````
private RectTransform Bpos; 

// this var holds the box sprite
    public GameObject menu;

// this var hold the button game object
    public GameObject button;

// vector to hold position
    Vector3 pos;

void Start(){
// sets vector to box position
       pos = menu.transform.position;

       //declairs button recttransform
            Bpos = button.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

       // sets button recttransformto pos vector
       button.Bpos = pos;

}```
i am currently getting the error at line (button,Bpos = pos;)

 error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'Bpos' and no accessible extension method 'Bpos' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
for the life of me i cant get this to work
````

Comment: You need to set the anchored position not the position when handling rect transforms, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html

Answer (score 0):

UI uses the anchoredPosition instead of the transform.position. You need to set the anchoredPosition of the button to the anchoredPosition of the menu. You can get the anchoredPosition by accessing the RectTransform. I would write it like that:

```
void Start(){
   // get anchoredPosition of menu and save it in pos
   pos = menu.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;

   // set anchoredPosition of the button to pos (anchoredPosition of menu)
   button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = pos

}
```